# How do I concat a character into a string?

Tags: c, string, char, cs50, strcat

I'm trying to take a char and add it to a string. OR if that's not possible, add it to an array of characters?

I tried changed 'string updated = ""' to 'char updated[text_length]' but I was getting the same error - incompatible integer to pointer conversion error

```
if(argc == 2 && IsDigitsOnly(argv[argc-1])) {
    // convert to integer
    int x = atoi(argv[argc-1]);

    // prompt user for plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int text_length = strlen(plaintext);
    int ascii = 'a';
    string updated= "";


    for (int i = 0; i < text_length; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                // GETTING ERROR HERE -- trying to pass 'letter' in strcat
                // This gives me an error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion error
                int n = (plaintext[i] + x) % 90;
                char letter = n;
                strcat(updated, letter);
            }
            else
            {
                ascii = (ascii + x) % 122;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", updated);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `string` and `get_string()` call, I assume that you are using `cs50`. In this case:

1. You can not write to a string literal (`updated`).
2. `srtcat` wants a pointer to `char` (not a `char`) as second parameter.

Switch to:

```
char updated[SOME_SIZE] = "";
...
char letter = n;
strcat(updated, (char[]){letter, 0});
```

Notice that `strcat` is prone to buffer overflows, consider replacing it with `snprintf`, something like:

```
char updated[SOME_SIZE] = "";
...
char letter = n;
size_t len = strlen(updated);

snprintf(updated + len, sizeof updated - len, "%c", letter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you mind explaining what's going on in this code "strcat(updated, (char[2]){letter, 0});" - trying to learn C at the moment

Comment: Of course, is a compound literal: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal

Answer (score 1):

> How do I concat a character into a string?

```
// Since C99, append by forming a compound literal.
strcat(some_string, (char []){some_chracter, '\0'});
```

Yet in OP's case, concatenating a character to a *string* is a weak approach.

For this task, `strcat(updated, ...)` is slow as each time a `letter` needs to be appended, `updated` is longer and longer.  See [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).

A more idiomatic approach would keep track of the length of `updated` and use that as an index in appending `letter`.

```
int text_length = strlen(plaintext);
int ascii = 'a';
// string updated= "";
char updated[text_length + 1]; // `text_length + 1` is the maximum size needed.
// Add
int updated_used  = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < text_length; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
    {
        if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            int n = (plaintext[i] + x) % 90;
            char letter = n;
            // strcat(updated, letter);
            updated[updated_used++] = letter;
        }
        else
        {
            ascii = (ascii + x) % 122;
        }
    }
}

// Add
updated[updated_used] = '\0';
```

---

Both `int n = (plaintext[i] + x) % 90;` and `ascii = (ascii + x) % 122;` look wrong.

I suspect OP wants to shift within uppercase letters with

```
int n = (plaintext[i] - 'A' + x) % 26 + 'A';
```

and for lower case:

```
int n = (plaintext[i] - 'a' + x) % 26 + 'a';
```